# How to use java program as a command in cmd?

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

I have a Java program utility that I want to execute as a command in cmd. I added the location to the PATH variable, but java programs needs to be executed using java - jar "...". How do I shorten that to just the program name, like mysql or netstat?

Update:
I neglected to mention that this java program takes arguments of its own to handle its tasks, so the batch program would need to pass the arguments passed to it over the the java program. I'm not skilled enough in batch to know how to do this.

~Jacob

Comment: What is the name of the Java class you want to run? and is it in a jar? and what is its package name?

Answer (score 4):

You could create a batch file or bash script (depending upon your OS) that calls the program with the proper java -jar commands, and simply name the batch (or bash) script whatever you would like to enter as the command. Place this in a directory that is in your PATH variable, and have at it.

**Edit:** Read [this](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php) for info on how to parse command line parameters in batch scripts. Just take the parameters passed to the batch file, parse them, and pass them to your jar file with:

`java -jar jarfile.jar param1 param2 ...`

So for example, lets's assume that your program takes two arguments. Your script could then be as follows:

```
java -jar jarfile.jar %1 %2
```

I am not an expert in batch files by any means, so there is probably a more proper way to do this. That being said, why over complicate things?

Comment: I posted an update in the questions as a response to your answer. By the way, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

With [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/index.html) you can wrap a Java program in a standalone executable file.  I'm not going to copy their (long) feature list here, but definite highlights are the numerous ways presented to customize the resulting exe, its small size, the fact that it's open source and its permissive license that allows commercial usage.

Comment: @M.M. in some cases, yes, but imagine a scenario where you don't have access to the sources, or no time to recompile the whole thing.  Also, in my experience it's not always trivial to get certain Java programs to work when compiled with eg gcj.  That's exactly the beauty of l4j, everything remains as it was (including dependencies on say specific jre versions as is often the case) - you can actually extract the jar that's stored inside the l4j generated executable, it's only things like deployment and launching that are streamlined.

Comment: This might work. I was hoping for a cleaner solution, but I will keep this in mind.